# How do I pass an object image linked by foreign-key into a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having trouble getting urls for the images attached to Car model objects in my Django project.

The goal is to fetch a single image from the uploaded set (perhaps by a pk, or the first one to be uploaded) to use as a thumbnail in the list view.

I've uploaded the images through the admin, but I can't fetch a single one from the template.

I've tried using the `<img src="{{ car.image.url }}">` (which is what worked when my image field was part of the Car model).

When looking at this in the rendered template, it's just the alt-text. Looking through developer tools shows `src(unknown)`

**models.py**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car_model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    vin = models.CharField('VIN', max_length=17, help_text='Enter the 17 character VIN number.', blank=True, null=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mileage')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    engine_displacement = models.CharField(default=2.0, max_length=3, help_text="Engine displacement in Liters (E.g. 2.0, 4.2, 6.3)")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
    help_text="Unique ID for this car")
...

class Image(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path)
```

**Template render**

```
 {% for car in most_recently_uploaded %}
                            <div class="col-xs-3 product-item" style="width:400px">
                                <figure class="figure"></figure>
                                    <a href="{{ car.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ car.image.url }}" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="{{ car.manufacturer }} {{ car.car_model }} image" ></a>
                                    <figcaption class="figure-caption"><a href="{{ car.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-link"><strong>{{ car.model_year }} {{ car.manufacturer }} {{ car.car_model }}</strong></a></figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass it to the template. Access it there via the reverse foreign key.

```
<img src="{{ car.image_set.first.image.url }}"
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Daniel, you're a hero on the Django SO forums